# How to draw on Bitmap in android?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to figure out how to draw on a bitmap in android, and keep a copy of these changed bitmaps for an undo function.

```
Bitmap b = ...
Paint p = new Paint();
canvas.drawBitmap(b, new Matrix(), null);
canvas.drawCircle(0,0,20,20);
//does Bitmap b have the circle drawn on it next time?
```

Or how do I get the bitmap after its been drawn on with the canvas(I want to preserve a stack of bitmaps with the changes applied by canvas drawing)? Maybe I'm going about this entirely wrong.

Answer (score 23):

Use [`new Canvas(Bitmap bitmap)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas(android.graphics.Bitmap)) to provide a `Canvas` with a `Bitmap` which will contain the result of your drawing operations.

The original `Bitmap` that you draw on your `Canvas` with `drawBitmap` will never be modified.

After each operation done by the user you might:

- keep in memory a list of the operations done
- save intermediate results to external storage with Bitmap.compress

Another approach could be to use a [`LayerDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) to stack successive drawing operations on top of each other. You can imagine allowing the user to disable each individual operation done.

Comment: Right now were just drawing a bunch of circles based on user touch event, but as more circles are drawn and held in memory it slows down considerably. That's why we were looking to "Save" user input/actions through applying the changes to a bitmap, that way only one bitmap is drawn each time instead of saving and drawing thousands of circles.

Comment: So you can use Bitmap.copy(...) on your destination Bitmap and provide the canvas with the resulting Bitmap as the new drawing destiation with Canvas.setBitmap()

Answer (score 0):

You can see complete guide how to draw text here:

https://www.skoumal.net/en/android-how-draw-text-bitmap/

Long story short:

Copy your bitmap to make it mutable and create Canvas based on it.