# How to draw Canvas on Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I`m building an android App, and i got stuck with a simple thing: How do i draw (or "add") a Canvas object, to another Canvas object, like "merging" them?

If that`s not possible, what is the best solution for doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends entirely on your implementation.

- If each Canvas draws objects directly from an array (of shapes, etc.) each frame, you could simply append one array to the other. This way, your Canvas does not need to be drastically altered, it only has to add one array to another (possibly an `ArrayList` would be the way to go here).
- If the above is not the case, you may have to make some more drastic changes. When I encountered a similar problem, I created a new method called `commitChanges()`, which added a series of changes to an existing Canvas (adding lines on top, etc.).

  1. I first invalidated the affected area, then created a Bitmap with the size of the Canvas: `Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGBA_8888);`.
  2. Next, I created a canvas from that Bitmap: `Canvas workingDrawing = new Canvas(bmp);`.
  3. Then, I drew everything I needed onto that new Canvas. In this case, that would be the data from one of your Canvases.
  4. Now, in your other Canvas, you have to get the Bitmap you just drew, then draw it onto this Canvas. Like so: `canvas.drawBitmap(yourDrawnBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);`.

I think the difficulty you'll face is transferring the data from one Canvas to another. But, regardless of your implementation, one of the above methods should work effectively for you.

Comment: I`m doing a sort of "simulator" for the robot i`m building to the competition, but, there are many "parts" that moves relatively to others, so i would have to calculate every relative part by hand. My idea was to create the canvas, and merge with the existing one, so that positioning, and rotating would`t be a problem. For example: a Body has a head, legs, feets... When i render "Body", it would call renderHead, and get the canvas of head, and then would place on the correct position and rotation. If Head has eyes, then in drawHead, i would call drawEyes and then join inside drawHead the eye..

Comment: What you COULD do in that case is to have off-screen Canvas objects that each have their own Bitmap object. In each Canvas, you can draw as many robot parts as you like (let's say, a hand and a forearm in one). Then you can render the Bitmap of that Canvas (and all the others) onto the "main" Canvas ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160149/how-to-draw-on-bitmap-in-android)). This may be quite hefty on the system, so your better bet is, as you said, to calculate each part relatively (as a hand is moved, it moves the arm as well). This way, you'd only need one Canvas.

Comment: Thanks! i will keep doing big calculations... :D

Comment: If you want to see what i`m talking about, go here: http://techlego.blogspot.com.br/search/label/rescue%20b It`s in portuguese, but you can use google translator! =]