# Android Map low performance for ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>

Tags: android, performance

I have

```
 public class MyItemsOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{
private List<OverlayItem> items=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Drawable marker=null;   
private StatusData data;    
private MapView mapView;
 private PopupPanel panel;

public MyItemsOverlay (Drawable defaultMarker, View view, LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater) {       
    super(defaultMarker);
      this.marker=defaultMarker;               
      mapView=(MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
      panel=new PopupPanel(R.layout.details_popup,getLayoutInflater, mapView);
      data=new StatusData (mapView.getContext());
      items=  protectedZoneData.GetItems();  

      populate();
}

 @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
      return(items.get(i));
    }


  @Override
    public int size() {
      return(items.size());
    }

  @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int i) {

      OverlayItem item=getItem(i);
      GeoPoint geo=item.getPoint();       

      View view=panel.getView();

      ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.latitude))
        .setText(String.valueOf(geo.getLatitudeE6()/1000000.0));
      ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.longitude))
        .setText(String.valueOf(geo.getLongitudeE6()/1000000.0));
      ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Name))
                              .setText(item.getTitle());
      ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Description))
                              .setText(item.getSnippet());

      panel.show();
      hidePopup();
      return(true);
    }
```

}

I need to load about 100 000 points.

And I have another overlay that will create polygon (100 000 polygons)

```
public class MyPolygonOverlay  extends Overlay{

private StatusData data; 

private Projection projection;
ArrayList<ArrayList<GeoPoint>> geArrayList;

public MyPolygonOverlay(Context context, MapView mapView)
{
    data=new StatusData(context);

    projection=mapView.getProjection();
    geArrayList=data.GetPoyigonGeoPoints();


}

public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow){
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);



    for (int i = 0; i < geArrayList.size(); i++) {
         Path path = new Path();
         ArrayList<GeoPoint> geoPoints=geArrayList.get(i);
         for (int j = 0; j <geoPoints.size(); j++) {

               GeoPoint gP1 =geoPoints.get(j);
               Point currentScreenPoint = new Point();

                Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
                projection.toPixels(gP1, currentScreenPoint);

                if (j == 0){
                  path.moveTo(currentScreenPoint.x, currentScreenPoint.y);                    

                }                  
                else
                {
                  path.lineTo(currentScreenPoint.x, currentScreenPoint.y);
                }
            }
           canvas.drawPath(path, GetPaint());

}
}
```

On zoom level 5 I load first overlay, then on zoom 8 I load second overlay.

How can I speed my application?

Answer (score 1):

Draw the Overlay on one bitmap and use that bitmap instead the redraw of each polygon.

You just need to calculate the scaling of your bitmap according your zoom level.

Comment: Hi, I am new to android. Do you have example for me?

Comment: Basically you just need to draw on a bitmap and store it. Read some tutorials about that or try that as a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160149/how-to-draw-on-bitmap-in-android You just need to create a bitmap and the drawing should be the same...

Comment: But bitmap will eat my memory?

Comment: Performance comes mostly comes with costs for memory. But one or two bitmaps shouldn't have such a huge impact on your memory consumption. And basically this is your only alternative (except for reducing the amount of points...)