# Canvas SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have custom SurfaceView, setting a background in onDraw method, then drawing canvas, but see only background. How can I draw with canvas on a background?
Tried to add a background with canvas, it works, but at top left 2-3dp was deleted, and redrawing every time background will eat a lot of memory.
So can it be done with 1st method or 2nd without empty spaces on top left?

Edit...

GameView.java

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
    private Bitmap background;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private GameManager gameLoopThread;

    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        gameLoopThread = new GameManager(this);
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                boolean retry = true;
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                while (retry) {
                    try {
                        gameLoopThread.join();
                        retry = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                gameLoopThread.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }
        });

        background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void drawCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
        if (x < getWidth() - 10) {
            x += 10;
        } else {
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
        }
        canvas.drawLine(0, 200, x, 200, paint);
    }
}
```

GameManager.java

```
public class GameManager extends Thread {
    private GameView view;
    private boolean running = false;

    public GameManager(GameView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        running = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                    view.drawCanvas(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(640, 400));
    }
}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.android.GameView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result is http://oi57.tinypic.com/15znrpy.jpg

If I comment GameView onDraw method and add canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null); to drawCanvas the result will be
http://oi60.tinypic.com/t0g802.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a specific way to set a SurfaceView's background.

If you set a background in `onDraw` then draw to the canvas somewhere outside of `onDraw`, it's going to call `onDraw` and draw the background over whatever was just drawn.

Redrawing the background every time will not eat a significant amount of memory, assuming you're not trying to do it on the UI thread.

Also, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "at top left 2-3dp was deleted" and "empty spaces on top left". Can you post an image of this, along with the code you've tried?

Comment: Maybe you should try it with a canvas that has a bitmap to draw on... Refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160149/how-to-draw-on-bitmap-in-android).

Comment: @Droid One thing that I would recommend to you is that if your background is static and won't be changing, have a separate view just for your background and then do any other drawing on another SurfaceView just for drawing. This will increase performance since you won't have to redraw the background every time. It will make a more noticeable difference if you're making something like a game where constant redrawing is required.

Comment: I tried to set a background to a parent SirfaceView, but it's always black.

Comment: @Droid You need to stack the SurfaceViews inside of a FrameLayout or similar. Then make the top SurfaceView have a transparent background. When you draw the background on the first canvas, don't do it on a bitmap, just the canvas. Also, I'm sure there are multiple ways of achieving similar results - if you, for some reason, aren't able to get this to work properly for you, try searching something like "draw background once in android" on Google, as that is the ultimate goal. If I get a chance later I can post a link with some sample code of how I have done it before and you can check that out.

Comment: Thank you very much, did it with
setZOrderOnTop(true);
setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);